# Can't import pod in Swift file in framework when removing use_frameworks! to build the pod as a static lib with Cocoapods 1.5.0

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I have a Swift framework. I removed `use_frameworks!` from my podfile and ran `pod install.` How do I get a swift file in my dynamic framework to recognize the files in the pod installed as a static lib?

Comment: What version of cocoapods are you using? From now on CocoaPods 1.5.0 comes with native support for building Swift pods as static libraries. 

Give this a read. blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-1.5.0/

Comment: @RizwanAhmed Thanks for the clarification. The reason I'm asking about static lib pods in relation to Swift is because I've updated to Cocoapods 1.5.0. A better phrasing of my question would have been 'Can't import pod in Swift file in framework when removing use_frameworks! to build the pod as a static lib with Cocoapods 1.5.0.' Question is now updated.

Comment: I'd like to add that I was able to successfully install a Swift pod as a static lib with Cocoapods 1.5.0 into a Swift app static lib target by importing the umbrella header from the pod in a bridging header for the static lib target. I still haven't figured out how to get a dynamic framework target to recognize a static lib pod.